# Prove that $f_{n}:[1,+\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \rightarrow \frac{x^n}{1+x^{n}}e^{-x}$ is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

By definition, I want to prove that $f_{n+1}(x)-f_{n}(x)\ge0$ for $x \in [1,+\infty[$

So, we obtain : $e^{-x}(\frac{x^{n+1}-x^{n}}{(1+x^{n+1})(1+x^{n})})$

But for $x \in [1,+\infty[$ we have : $e^{-x}>0$, and also $(1+x^{n+1})(1+x^{n})>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

and we know that : the sequence $(x^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing which means that :

$x^{n+1}-x^{n}\ge 0$ so $f_n$ is increasing.

Is this method correct ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

No, you are on the wrong trace. To prove that $f_n(x)$ is increasing, you should pick $x_1<x_2$ and show that $f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$.

Or you can verify that $f_n'(x)>0$.

Comment: This depends whether the goal is to show that it an increasing function of $n$ or $x$.

Comment: It seems to be for $x$ fixed

Comment: Really not. We say that a function $f(x)$ is increasing always depends $x$.

Comment: Agreed.... if we were looking at this as a function of $n$ then that would be a different story, but this is a function of $x$.

Comment: We define $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing if $\forall x \in [1,+\infty[$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f_{n} (x) \le f_{n+1} (x)$